# How to download a `geojson` file with Panda from Google Colab?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm a newbie in `python` and `panda` and I use `Google Colab`.
I have a dataframe I manipulate in many ways. This is OK.
At the end of my manipulations I have a returned `geojson` formatted data:

```
for record in json_result:
geojson['features'].append({
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [
                        [ 
                         [ record['tlx'],  record['tly'] ],
                         [ record['blx'],  record['bly'] ],
                         [ record['brx'],  record['bry'] ],
                         [ record['trx'],  record['try'] ],
                         [ record['tlx'],  record['tly'] ],
                        ]],
    },
    'properties': {"surface": record['SURFACE']},
})
```

The output (`geojson`) is good; I don't think I have any problem here.
However I want to download this `geojson` file to my computer.

I've tried numerous ways, without success.

```
from google.colab import files
......
```

How to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mount your google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Save your `geojson` object:

```
import json

# create json object from dictionary
geojson_str = json.dumps(geojson)

# open file for writing, "w" 
f = open("drive/MyDrive/geojson_export.json","w")

# write json object to file
f.write(geojson_str)

# close file
f.close()
```